# Ionic 3, HTTP native vs. HttpClient

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-httpclient

I am struggling to make HTTP native or HttpClient get to work for my app.

If I run `ionic serve -c` I get HttpClient working good on my browser at localhost:8100 and in Ionic Dev App. If I build for Android though, HttpClient fails thus I decided to give HTTP Native a try.

Then I don't understand how I could get some console log if that native plugin is not supported from Ionic Dev App ([here says](https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/devapp#native-cordova-plugin-support)), neither I can see on my browser cause of Cordova is not present.

Is there a way to log on a device to debug HTTP Native?

Comment: you can use `axios` library for HTTP calls. it will work in both browser and device.
check this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should debug your application connect your phone to your laptop and

1. Open your Google Chrome Browser
2. Go to Inspect  **(Ctrl + Shift +I)**
3. Go To More Tools [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2W3c.png)
4. Open Remote devices and inspect your device

For more information [click here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You wont see native http calls log to the browser since they are called native from the device and never are called from the browser, but if you are debugging while connected to xcode, the xcode debugging output should give some information about your native HTTP calls success and failure.

Answer (score 0):

Following @vd_virani answer, here is a quick link to inspect a device from Chrome

```
chrome://inspect/#devices
```

Plug your device via USB, then copy & paste this link in your Chrome address bar like a website.